# Simple contrary examples to show that $\left \| \cdot \right \|_1$ is not unitary invariant for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrix norm $\left \| \cdot \right \|_1$ is not unitary invariant. Show this for as simple as possible $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and a unitary $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that (1) $\left \| A \right \|_1 > \left \| QA \right \|_1$ and (2) $\left \| A \right \|_1 < \left \| QA \right \|_1$.

(Hint: first look at a $2 \times 2$ case, then extend it to the $n \times n$ case.)

Comment: added an hint for the other case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take something like an rotation so 
$$Q=\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\alpha)\\
\sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$$ 
with $\alpha =\frac{\pi}{4}$ and use $A=I$ for bigger matrix just take it as a submatrix. Use unit vectors to prove the not invariance.

That works fine for (2) notice that with $B=QA$ you will get (1) when chosing $Q^T B=Q^T QA=A$